# Conexão Intel XDK com banco de dados Mysql

Tags: mysql, plugin, conexão, intel

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a conexão da minha aplicação com banco de dados externo no Intel XDK. 
Alguém poderia me indicar qual outras técnicas de conectar a minha aplicação com um banco de dados externo, além da possibilidade de desenvolver um webservice com php e xml/json? Existe algum plugin que faça isso no Intel XDK?

Comment: ou você utiliza o LocalStorage do html5 com limite de 5 mb ou você utiliza um webservice desenvolvido na linguagem que quiser para fazer a interface de banco.

Comment: Resolvi criar uma consulta no banco e gerar um arquivo XML com php disponibilizando os dados via POST. Como eu conseguiria recuperar esses dados fazendo uma requisição HTTP e exibir os dados no HTML com JavaScript/Jquery?